# Nested Thymeleaf Templates in Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

**Short version**

How is one supposed to make nested templates in Thymeleaf when using Spring? It appears [asterisk notation is not supported](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Using-conditional-logic-in-th-object-td4028232.html) (`"*{mailingAddress}"`) inside `th:object` attributes in Spring. Is there a work-around / different tag to use?

**Long version**

For example, let's say I have these classes:

```
class Address { String street; }
class Person { Address mailingAddress; Address shippingAddress; }
class Order { int orderNo; Person customer; }
```

So I make an `address.html` Thymeleaf template:

```
<span th:text="*{street}"></span>
```

We test it with a sample `Address`. Looks good.

and I make a `person.html` Thymeleaf template that references the address like so:

```
<span th:text="*{firstName}"></span>
<span th:object="${person.shippingAddress}">
    <span th:include="fragments/address :: address"></span>
</span>
```

And we test it with an example person. I could even reference the same template and set the context to be the `${person.mailingAddress}`. So far so good.

Now let's make our `Order` template. Only, hey, wait. Earlier, in our `person.html` file we said `${person.shippingAddress}` but *now* we need it to say `${order.customer.shippingAddress}`. [If I were not using Spring](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Using-conditional-logic-in-th-object-td4028232.html) I'd put the following into `person.html`:

```
<span th:text="*{firstName}"></span>
<span th:object="*{shippingAddress}">
    <span th:include="fragments/address :: address"></span>
</span>
```

That way, no matter what my path to getting here all I have to care about is that my current context has a `shippingAddress`. I could then use `person.html` directly as well as within my `order.html` template.

Unfortunately I *am* in Spring, so I get the following exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
    The expression used for object selection is *{shippingAddress},
    which is not valid: only variable expressions (${...}) are
    allowed in 'th:object' attributes in Spring-enabled environments. 
    (include:510)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringObjectAttrProcessor.validateSelectionValue(SpringObjectAttrProcessor.java:73)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSelectionAttrProcessor.getNewSelectionTarget(AbstractStandardSelectionAttrProcessor.java:69)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSelectionTargetAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSelectionTargetAttrProcessor.java:61)
```

To move forward I must duplicate all my nested templates. In this example, I would have one `person.html` with `th:object="${person.mailingAddress}"` calling to `address.html`, and a duplicate of `person.html` called `orderCustomer.html` where we change the line to `th:object="${order.customer.mailingAddress}"`, but is otherwise identical.

Is there a work-around out there that would let me re-use templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can report a bug to the thymeleaf developers in github, or fork the project to add this functionality and convince the Daniel Fernández to accept it.

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues

Or else, he is available in StackOverflow. You can simply send him a message about the posibility of integrating this functionality

https://stackoverflow.com/users/550664/daniel-fern%C3%A1ndez

apart from that there is nothing much we can do rather to stick with the approach of putting `th:object="${person.mailingAddress}"` and `th:object="${order.customer.mailingAddress}"` outside each import.